# Copy the formula to another sheet and paste it as values to specific columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble whenever i try to run this code. It works fine but when the other columns are empty it continuously run the formula. It must stop running the formula if the next columns are empty. How can i do that with my existing code. Thank you
please see my codes below.

```
     Sub L4FORMULA()
     Dim rngFor As Range
     Dim RNG1 As Range
     Dim LastRow As Long

     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     Set rngFor = Sheet2.Range("P2")
     Set RNG1 = Sheet2.Range("U2")

    Sheet4.Activate

    LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("B:B"))

    rngFor.Copy Sheet4.Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
    Sheet4.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Calculate
        Sheet4.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Value = Sheet4.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Value

    RNG1.Copy Sheet4.Range("U2:U" & LastRow)
    Sheet4.Range("U2:U" & LastRow).Calculate
        Sheet4.Range("U2:U" & LastRow).Value = Sheet4.Range("U2:U" & LastRow).Value

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   End Sub
```

Comment: yes @aaa thanks, could you know what is wrong to my codes? why should the code continuously run even though other column are empty.

Comment: I cannot see anything in that code that would make it run on any column other than P and U and then only once.

Comment: yes @Jeeped but i want to run the columns in P and U with data in other columns, what this code is doing is to run even though the other columns are empty. But i already resolved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my question, i just replace the range of the Lastrow declaration.
Thanks for all the help.

```
LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted answer. Btw, you might want to consider other approach in finding the last row as this approach has a flaw, it will fail to consider blank cells.